# Filtering QUERY_STRING with back references in RewriteCond

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, backreference

I have a PHP script used to process images before displaying them on the web page. The query string has to be checked to reject all requests coming from external domains.
If TLD is example.com

```
http://example.com/process.php?img=somepath/images/imgX.png OK
http://example.com/process.php?img=http://example.com/anotherpath/folder/images/imgX.png OK
http://example.com/process.php?img=http://anotherdomain.com/images/someimg.jpg Rejected!
```

This rewrite rules work on my test server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http://
RewriteCond expr "! %{QUERY_STRING} -strmatch '*%{HTTP_HOST}*'"
RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

But on the production server this doesn't work. After some headaches and searching I found that expr is not supported before Apache 2.4...
From what I read I can use atomic back-references to check if the %{HTTP_HOST} is present in the %{QUERY_STRING}. The idea is to construct something like this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}::%{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)::/\1/?
```

Which obviously doesn't work in the current state. Any help and further explanation on this syntax will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http://` allowing `?img=somepath/images/imgX.png` query string?

Comment: That's the point, it does not allow it. Since the condition is not met, the rest is ignored, the RewriteRule Forbidden is not applied and the request is processed normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in Apache 2.2:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} [a-zA-Z0-9_]=http://
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)#.*?\1
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

`\1` is back-reference for `HTTP_HOST`

Modified the RewriteCond to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#.*#%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)#.*?\1
```

This captures any URL structure. JF

Comment: Thanks anubhava I have just tried your solution but it is not working. (no filtering is performed).

Comment: I have tested it throughly with all 3 cases and works as expected on my Apache.

Comment: Must be out of luck today ;) Tested on 2 servers (Apache 2.2 and 2.4) not working so far. The rule doesn't reject query strings containing an external domain.
I have no other rule in my .htaccess file

Comment: I have also tested this on 2 Apache versions 2.2 an 2.4 and it worked in both. Are you testing with exact same URL shown in question? What's not working? Are you not getting 403 at all?

Comment: No, the URLs shown in the question were just examples, the structure can be different. Sorry I should have been more specific. I did a small tweak to your RewriteCond and now it works with any URL. Adding a .* between the 2 variables did the trick. RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#.*#%{QUERY_STRING} !^([^#]+)#.*?\1 Thanks for your help, very much appreciated :)

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do this in PHP land then you can use `parse_url`.

[Link to PHP documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

Comment: I obviously already have implemented this in the php file but want to have an extra layer of security at server level.